# Kernel Panic: not syncing: VFS unable

Tags: 12.04, boot, kernel, sync

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and have been  using it for a while.

I just rebooted today and got this error:

```
Kernel Panic: not syncing: VFS Unable to mount root fs on unknown_block(0,0)`
```

Here is a screen shot the [error](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8okdvn-27_ydkloSlNCcUVIWnc/edit?usp=sharing). I used the boot repair disk and tried to fix it but it did not work.  Here is there result of that [results](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7033715). I am at a loss as to how to fix this.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Your `uuid` of `/dev/sda1` is correctly applied to grub.cfg. You probably need to boot from rescue disk, drop a shell and

```
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
```